# hyperscript equvelant of jquery .on("click"

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperscript

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    var counter = 0;

    $("button").click(function() {
        e="<p class='test' _=\"on click append 'click me' to value of the #search\">click me</p>"
        $("h2").append(e)
    });

    // With on():

    $("h2").on("click", "p.test", function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/hyperscript.org@0.8.1"></script>

<input id="search" />
<button>generate new element</button>
<h2></h2>
```

The jquery works, but the hyperscript doesn't append text to the input box.

Comment: What code have you written? You haven’t written any _hyperscript

Comment: `on click append 'click me' to value of the #search` @JoJoYawson

Comment: Do you want to append text _next_ to the input box, or _inside_ of the input box?

Comment: inside @JoJoYawson

Comment: Just call `_hyperscript.browserInit()` after append `$("h2").append(e)`

Answer (score -1):

Well, your hyperscript code appears to work like you intended. The jQuery seems to be the broken one. If you mean to append to the value that the user is typing. Ditch the jQuery appending and just use _hyperscript.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/hyperscript.org@0.8.1"></script>
<input id="search" />
<button _="on click append 'click me' to value of the #search">generate new element</button>
<h2></h2>
```

Comment: but my HTML is generated by the backend, this is why I wrote a jquery script to simulate the situation. I have already given up on hyperscript, as it is not as convenient as jquery for me.